# mongodb insertOne() slower on production than dev

Tags: mongodb, next.js

i've got a new nextjs app based off the mongodb template. i make a simple insertOne and then reload the page. this works perfectly on my local machine:

```
const submitComment = async(e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      try {
       let response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/addPost`, 
{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({comment}),
        headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
       });
      response = await response.json();
      window.location.reload();
    }catch(err: any) {
      // console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`)
    }
  }
```

the page reloads after an insert and i see my latest record. on prod, the process takes several seconds so my window reload doesn't catch my latest record. so i have to refresh the page again. what am i missing? here's how i fetch my data on page load:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const posts = await getPosts();

  return {
    props: {
       posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts))
    },
    revalidate: 10
  };
};
```

And this is my getPosts() method:

```
let client;
let posts: any;

async function init() {
    try {
         client = await clientPromise;
        posts = client.db('hors-service').collection('posts');
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to establish connection to 
database');
    }
}

;(async () => {
    await init()
})()

export async function getPosts() {
    try {
        if(!posts) await init();
        const result = await posts
            .find()
            .map(
                (post: { _id: { toString: () => any; }; }) => ({...post, _id: 
post._id.toString()}))
            .sort( {
                _id: -1
            })
            .toArray();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        return { error: 'Failed to fetch posts'};
    }
}
```

Here's the mongo configuration file which is standard for NextJS/MongoDB integration:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<any>;

declare global {
  var _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the 
value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot 
Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global 
variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in 
a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

Comment: How many posts are there? Your `getPosts()` function gets all posts in the database, so that will slow down pretty quickly as the number of posts grows.

Comment: at this point, 100 posts total.

Comment: Would this happen to be Atlas free tier?

Comment: Yes. I was afraid of that.

Comment: That could be the reason. 100 documents isn't a lot for a true "production grade" database deployment (unless they're enormous documents), but Atlas free tier is known to slow down *very* quickly as the number of documents scanned increases. Still, it seems like you should be able to make your server not send a response until the insert finishes, so then when you reload, the new documents will be in the database even if the insert operations takes quite long.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I'm thinking that my code could be wrong. The submitComment() method does await the response before it does a window.location.reload(). It just seems like this part is being skipped.

Comment: The code definitely looks like it won't refresh until the server sends a response. Could you add the backend code of the `addPost` endpoint, including any Mongo queries made there?

Comment: the .find() is the standard way to call Mongo from NextJS app. I did add the extra boilerplate above that snippet and the mongo configuration file at the end of the post. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I've read the Mongo Atlas documents more closely, as I should have done earlier. M0 is for dev environments so I've updated to M2; also for dev environments and low traffic apps. Thank you for your help,

Comment: Are you using a read preference of primary?